# Nginx request path variable?

Tags: nginx

I want to accomplish something like

`https://companyname.net/admin/identity` routed to `https://localhost:9443`
`https://companyname.net/admin/identity/a/b/c` routed to `https://localhost:9443/a/b/c`

How to do those the neatest possible way?

Current Config:

```
location /admin/identity$path {
  proxy_pass https://localhost:9443$path;
}
```

Comment: http://serverfault.com/a/586614/211028

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's copy of an answer from https://serverfault.com/a/586614/211028

```
location /admin/identity/ {
    proxy_pass https://localhost:9443/;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

try location config like this:

```
location ~ /admin/identity/(.*) {
    proxy_pass https://localhost:9443/$1;
}
```

Comment: That does not match /admin/identity, only /admin/identity/